# Display a default DataTemplate in a ContentControl when its content is null or empty?

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, default-value, contentcontrol

I would think this is possible, but the obvious way isn't working.

Currently, I'm doing this:

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding HurfView.EditedPart}">
    <ContentControl.Resources>
        <Style
            TargetType="ContentControl"
            x:Key="emptytemplate">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger
                    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Content}"
                    Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter
                        Property="ContentControl.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid
                                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <TextBlock>EMPTY!</TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

I'm not getting any binding errors and this compiles.  However, it doesn't produce the expected result.  I've also tried the obvious:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Null}"><TextBlock>Hurf</TextBlock></DataTemplate>
```

This won't compile.  And attempting to set the content twice fails as well:

```
<ContentControl
    Content="{Binding HurfView.EditedPart}">
        <TextBlock>DEFAULT DISPLAY</TextBlock>
</ContentControl>
```

Can I do this without writing a custom template selector?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Simple, you have to bind the content property in the style. Styles won't overwrite a value on a control if there's a binding present, even if the value evaluates to Null. Try this.

```
<ContentControl>
    <ContentControl.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{Binding HurfView.EditedPart}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=Content}" Value="{x:Null}">
                    <Setter Property="ContentControl.Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                    <TextBlock>EMPTY!</TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ContentControl.Style>
</ContentControl>
```

Comment: No problem it's a very common mistake people make when trying to do more complex things with styles and triggers.

Comment: Every time I come back for this I'm going to leave a comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Y Halo thar.  Best solution to a failed Converter as well.  Just return `null` from the conversion process and trap for it this way.  Can't do it using Validation, unfortunately...

Comment: It's the gift that keeps on giving, and the beauty of Stackoverflow.

Comment: Well, at least 100 rep this time.

Comment: Its so much easier to come back here than to look through my codebase to find another example.  Maybe I should just create a custom ContentControl...

Comment: Hmm this won't work for me, I'm using the TransitionControl from here, and it crashes because Template.FindName("PART_ContentHost", this); returns null...

Comment: @RvdK Name the Grid (or other top-level panel) PART_ContentHost

Answer (score 27):

Since I stumbled upon this question and had the same problem today, I wanted to contribute another way how I solved the problem. Since I did not like to add another style trigger I used the property `TargetNullValue` which seems to be a bit more readable than the accepted solution (which works nevertheless):

```
    <ContentControl>
      <ContentControl.Content>
        <Binding Path="ContentViewModel">
          <Binding.TargetNullValue>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
              <TextBlock>EMPTY!</TextBlock>
            </Grid>
          </Binding.TargetNullValue>
        </Binding>
      </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
```

Comment: this is an elegant solution with the TargetNullValue. Nice find

Comment: Works, but in some cases like mine it produces Binding-Errors. Although I also think this one is more readable, check for new Binding-Errors when using it.

Comment: Also have a look here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22315699/wpf-textblock-targetnullvalue-not-working] to learn about the `FallbackValue` attribute in case `TargetNullValue` alone does not do the trick

Answer (score 2):

You could return DBNull.Value as the FallbackValue of the Binding for the Content of the ContentControl, and create a DataTemplate for DBNull :

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DBNull}">
    <!-- The default template -->
</DataTemplate>

...

<ContentControl Content="{Binding HurfView.EditedPart, FallbackValue={x:Static system:DBNull.Value}}" />
```

Comment: That's kinda weird...  It was my understanding the preferred method was to return [DependencyProperty.UnsetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx).  I've done this in some type converters and it worked well...

Comment: @Will, yes, that would probably be better. I wrote that answer more than one year ago, and my understanding of WPF at the time was still very incomplete...

Comment: @Will can you add an answer using DependencyProperty.UnsetValue

Comment: @Simon_Weaver um, no?  Because I have no idea why you would need one?  Is the selected answer not correct?

Comment: I used `TargetNullValue={x:Static system:DBNull.Value}` and `<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:DBNull}">`, and works great