# WPF Textblock TargetNullValue not working?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textblock, targetnullvalue

I have a wpf textblock as below:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding [someViewModel].SomeVar.SomeSubVar.Name, 
                          TargetNullValue='-'}"/>
```

At my viewmodel side, I'll have my own logic that in the end, `SomeVar.SomeSubVar` will be null.

If I want to show a default value for this `TextBlock` I know I can declare and initiate `SomeVar.SomeSubVar` and assign default value into `SomeVar.SomeSubVar.Name` but I would like to use `TargetNullValue` instead. May I know which part is wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You might look at using FallbackValue http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue(v=vs.110).aspx in conjunction with TargetNullValue.

In order for TargetNullValue to work you must be able to evaluate the full path of [someViewModel].SomeVar.SomeSubVar.Name to null. If 'someViewModel', 'SomeVar', or 'SomeSubVar' are null then 'Name' can never be evaluated, and TargetNullValue won't apply.

Answer (score 4):

The `Binding's TargetNullValue` property is displayed in the `TextBlock` if the `[somveViewModel].SomeVar.SomeSubVar.Name` property is null.  It doesn't cane the value of the `[somveViewModel].SomeVar.SomeSubVar.Name` property.  It effectively sets up an equivalency between null and the `TargetNullValue` property's value.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895453/set-value-to-null-in-wpf-binding) for a good explanation.

So my advice is if you want to have a non-null default value, you need to set it in the view model.

Comment: This is what appears to happen, however this is not explained at all in the linked question. In fact, there are a lot of confusing answers and comments posted on that question.

Comment: I made a new question regarding TargetNullValue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36402291/why-does-targetnullvalue-update-nullable-source