# Why does TargetNullValue update nullable Source

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, nullable

[`TargetNullValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue(v=vs.110).aspx) is supposed to update the binding `Target` when the binding `Source` evaluates to `null`:

> Gets or sets the value that is used in the target when the value of the source is null.

In addition to that it also appears to set the `Source` to `null` (if possible), when the value of `Target` is equals to given `TargetNullValue`. In other words, it effectively sets up an equivalency between `null` and the `TargetNullValue` property's value. However this is not mentioned in the documentation at all.

See this example:

```
<Window x:Class="WPF_Sandbox.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPF_Sandbox"
        Title="MainWindow"
        x:Name="ThisControl">
    <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel">
        <TextBox x:Name="MyTextBox" Text="{Binding NullableInt, ElementName=ThisControl, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>


public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private int? nullableInt;

    public int? NullableInt
    {
        get { return nullableInt; }
        set { nullableInt = value; }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Note: `UpdateSourcetrigger` is only set to make testing easier and has nothing to do with the effect in question.

If you put a breakpoint in `NullableInt`'s setter, you can see that it gets triggered (with `value == null`) when you change the `TextBox` content to `''`.

Is this a undocumented behavior by `TargetNullValue` or is there some other side effect in play here?

Edit:
I stumbled upon this topic, because I was looking at this question:
[Set value to null in WPF binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895453/set-value-to-null-in-wpf-binding)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be undocumented behavior.  If you look at [BindingExpressionBase.GetRawProposedValue()](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Data/BindingExpressionBase.cs,1114) when retreiving the value to use, it actually checks to see if the value is equal to the TargetNullValue and if so, uses `null` instead:

```
internal virtual object GetRawProposedValue()
{
    object value = Value;

    // TargetNullValue is the UI representation of a "null" value.  Use null internally.
    if (Object.Equals(value, EffectiveTargetNullValue))
    {
        value = null;
    }

    return value;
}
```

(where `EffectiveTargetNullValue` is ultimately the `TargetNullValue`).

Indeed, if you set your `TargetNullValue` to be `5` instead of an empty string, you'll see that typing `5` will reset the property to null.